# How to apply multiple conditions to dataframe with loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe

```
dict1 = {'x_math_lp': {'John':'0',
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn': '2'},
         'o_math_lp': {'John': 0.005,
                       'Lisa': 0.001,
                       'Karyn':0.9}}
df= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I would like to apply a condition such that if a value in the first column is less than 1 and the value in the 2nd column if >= 0.05, then replace the value in the first column with 'NaN'

Results should look like this

```
       x_math_lp    o_math_lp
John    NaN          0.005
Lisa    1            0.001
Karyn   NaN          0.900
```

Note: The reason why I want to use a loop is because my true dataframe has 30 columns and I was to do it for every column pair set in the dataframe, essentially, updating the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc` for your desired column and check you condition like below. *(Because some number in `x_math_lp` is `str` you can use  `pd.to_numeric`)*

Try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df.x_math_lp = pd.to_numeric(df.x_math_lp, errors='coerce')
>>> df.loc[((df['x_math_lp'] < 1) | (df['o_math_lp'] >= 0.005)), 'x_math_lp'] = np.nan
>>> df
       x_math_lp    o_math_lp
John    NaN         0.005
Lisa    1           0.001
Karyn   NaN         0.900
```

If you want to run on multiple columns for every column pair you can use this:

```
>>> df= pd.DataFrame({'x_math_lp': {'John': 0,'Lisa': 1,'Karyn': 2},'o_math_lp': {'John': 0.005,'Lisa': 0.001,'Karyn':0.9},'y_math_lp': {'John': 0,'Lisa': 1,'Karyn': 2},'p_math_lp': {'John': 0.005,'Lisa': 0.001,'Karyn':0.9}})
>>> columns = df.columns
>>> for a,b in  zip(columns[::2],columns[1::2]):
...    df.loc[((df[a] < 1) | (df[b] >= 0.005)), a] = np.nan
>>> df

       x_math_lp    o_math_lp   y_math_lp   p_math_lp
John     NaN         0.005            NaN   0.005
Lisa     1.0         0.001            1.0   0.001
Karyn    NaN         0.900            NaN   0.900
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The result is correct but it doesn't apply the condition if df['o_math_lp'] is less than zero. Both conditions need to be met and then we update the first column.

Comment: Is the first condition missing? `df.loc[(df['x_math_lp'] < 1) | (df['o_math_lp'] >= 0.005), 'x_math_lp'] = np.nan`. (He explained his question with 'and' but I put `or` operator according to expected output.)

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I'm going to try and use this to generate a loop to deal with my whole dataset.